# Architecture recommendation for authentication and authorization in a multi tenant platform

Tags: .net, authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, multi-tenant

We are designing a new software platform based on the Microsoft .Net  platform. The platform is multi-tenant supporting our current clients. Some of the architecture decisions are
1. The database is multi-tenant(Azure Sql) where all tables have a tenant Id column providing logical separation of data
2. The first phase will be a responsive website built in MVC.
3. The data access layer is built using Web API. This is to allow us to use the same layer for a mobile App in phase 2 and also for providing end points to out clients for data pulls as they need it.
4. The user accounts will be created by us internally & application access shall be based on the users email identifiers- like Jim@company1.com or Sid@company2.com. Users will have a role assigned which will determine authorization to parts of the platform.

The pressing architecture decision for us is the Authentication/Authorization strategy. The goal is to authenticate users, generate an access token which will be passed with every data request. The access token can be deconstructed, used to identify the tenant the user belongs to, his role and the data can be retrieved.

I have been reading up on OAuth2 and the architecture of the token with the header and the payload. But it seems as if its more for Authorization to the API then user authentication. Am I reading OAuth2 correctly that it is not a suitable solution for Authentication or am I wrong in my assumptions?

What is the modern standard for implementing Authentication/Authorization? I know we have Asp.net Identity but want other people's opinions based on their experience